# Can $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}=4$ have positive integer solutions.

Tags: number-theory

Can $$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}=4$$ have positive integer solutions.
It's just a problem from some forum. I translate it into this form. Tried some triples but fail. Also I can't prove it doesn't exist integer solutions.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-positive-integer-solutions-to-frac-x-y+z-+-frac-y-z+x-+-frac-z-x+y-4?fbclid=IwAR2QXMaIvzzmFnheWxd2NAdAakrrArM4CKHt0w0h6ufMMilN0QjTbnmCVV8

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264754/solution-to-a-diophantine-equation/275193#275193